# What is the name of a dry plant in circular shape which bounces off the ground from side to side to symbolize abandoned city (i.e. in Wild West)?

Tags: effects

It's pretty much all in the title: What is the name of a dry plant in circular shape which bounces off the ground from side to side of the screen to symbolize abandoned city/place (i.e. in Wild West)?

Comment: Sometimes it's not just about abandoned towns, but also when a character stumbles or blows into town and wrecks havoc, leaving a line of destruction in it's wake. It's a metaphor for someone or something that doesn't have any roots or capacity to grow them.

Comment: This seems more like a question in search of English vocabulary than anything else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's the same as if you ask a question that gets no answers…

**[Tumbleweed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumbleweed)**.

Comment: That's it, thank you! :) I appreciate the joke as well :D

Comment: One of the best answers I have ever seen. *slow clap*